# anchor tag seems to not be closed

Tags: php, html

What is wrong with my code here, when I click on the ending  tag in this bit of html it doesnt light up as having a partner.  I think its probably related to the PHP in the code but I am not sure.  The link does work in safari and chrome but has trouble in other browsers. Please let me know what you think

```
 <td class="stat">
      <a data-ajax="false" href="following.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_user']?>">
        <div class="statnum"><?php echo $row2['COUNT(username)']?></div>
        <div class="statlabel">FOLLOWING</div>
      </a>
```

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: Unrelated but, `SELECT COUNT(username) as total_users FROM yada....` Then you can use `$row2['total_users']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML 4.x, an `<a>` element cannot contain a `<div>` element.

This changed in HTML 5, but:

- Some browsers have issues with it, especially if you do not explicitly set `display: block` on the `<a>`
- Your editor's syntax highlighter may not have caught up with that change

Comment: ok would that be why its not clickable in the google android browser?